# Access method of calling class

Tags: java

i want to access method of calling class when method in called class is triggered. Following is the example i want to do. The class that is making the instance of classes C is called randomly. so when the listerners method is triggered the calling class' interface method should be able to listen that tigger.Thats what i want to do

```
Interface myinterface
{
    public void interfacemethod(); 
}

class A implements myinterface
{  
    C instance = new C ();

    public void interfacemethod()
}

class B implements myinterface
{    
    C instance = new C ();
    public void interfacemethod()
}

Class C extends someListerner
{
    public void listenercalled()
    {
        //here i want to call the callers interfacemethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: please answer the question before -ve marking and if marking -ve please tell thhe reason also

Comment: I'm curious about this real world use case.

Comment: Do you just want to call the super class method? If so can't you just do `super.interfacemethod()`?

Comment: i am working on beacons and i have various type of beacons and single beaconhelper class that tracks various beacons .. and i have various types of beacons to call that beaconhelper .  beaconhelper listens to enter and exit event of beacon and i dont want to make if else in that beaconhelper to know the type of beacon instead i want to call the function to save those beacon on beaconhelper calling class on enter and exit trigger

Comment: @ReeceKenney how can i call super.interfacemethod() ???? think of the senario i am talking about

Comment: In C#, the method signature is often `method(object sender, ...)` so you can access the caller.

Comment: if i send the object i must know before hand which class is calling it to type cast it .. but i dont know which class may call it .. it purely dynamic

Comment: you should use **Observer Pattern**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to the caller object.

If you are trying to call C's creator's Myinterface object, pass a Myinterface pointer in the C constructor.

C instance = new C(this);

Store that pointer in your C class and use it for the callback.  Java functions are "virtual" by default.  That means, regardless of casting, the lowest subclass function will be called (which is what you want, I think).

```
Interface Myinterface{
   public void interfacemethod(); 
}

class A implements Myinterface
{  
    C instance = new C ((Myinterface)this);

    public void interfacemethod()
}

class B implements Myinterface
{    
    C instance = new C ((Myinterface)this);
    public void interfacemethod()
}

Class C extends someListerner
{
    Myinterface ml;
    public C(Myinterface arg_ml){
        ml = arg_ml;
    }
    public void listenercalled()
    {
        ml.interfacemethod();
        //here i want to call the callers interfacemethod()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give an example by writing the code to make me understand better

Comment: Java uses virtual functions by default, so, even cast as a Myinterface, the respective A or B interface will be called, which is what you are looking for, if I understand you.

Comment: I can try, I'm new to stack overflow, so formatting is tricky.

Comment: A and B are the class that implements my interface which needs to called on the trigger of class C's listerner. and like class A and B there can be more class which will instanciate class c .

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for, I guess.  Do you want C's listener called to call the class that instantiates C?

Comment: Reading your comments, I think you believe Java functions are not virtual.  Java functions are virtual.  The lowest class will be called, no matter what the casting.

Comment: C instance = new C(this); is not = public C(Mylistner arg_ml) because with this u pass the context of calling class but at the reciveing end it recieves an interface

Comment: I had assumed Java handled the casting implicitly.  It has been a while since I worked with Java.  If it doesn't work, cast it to be a Myinterface.  The respective A or B function will still be called because Java functions are virtual.

Comment: can you please upvote the question since it was a legible question that can be asked